How to use Android permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA
I am planning to build a system application for my android device that allows me to programically delete another application's data (not cache).
The use case is to simulate restarting the app to it's fresh state when an event occurs, i.e. changing of network etc. It is for data security purposes and I want to build a proof of concept with an AOSP rom before proceeding further.
Right now, I had entered:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"/>

in my AndroidManifest.xml file, but I do not know how to execute this function in the MainActivity.kt file.
Also, I have a really basic app with no UI, just running this function to show the concept working state.
I had tried to find other solutions online but most are either clear caches or just people saying it is not possible because it is a privileged function (I understand this, which is why I am trying to build an app for AOSP rom so that I can install it as a system level app instead of a user app)
Also to note, I have also tried trying to execute these lines of code in my app as well:
val cmd = arrayOf("pm", "clear", "com.publisher.application")
val process: Process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)

but as the device is not rooted (and it will not be when the device is in use), I could not get this to work.
If anybody could figure out a way to let me pragmatically delete another app's data, with any privilege permissions (except for root), do let me know as well. Thank you!
PS: I am not too familiar with Kotlin nor Android development in general. But I do know a bit of Java programming, so I can roughly understand certain lines of code, but not too much

You have the option to utilize PackageManager.clearApplicationUserData(packageManager, observer) method with the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"/> requested, which is a hidden API. To circumvent the imposed restriction, you can employ reflection since it is not included in the block list. Alternatively, you can make use of the modified android.jar obtained from AOSP.
